# jQuery .select() is not working on mobile devices

Tags: jquery, select, mobile, input

I am working on one site where the requirement is to allow visitors to copy a code using single click. Something like we used to copy coupon codes on some sites using single click.

For this I've used jQuery as below:

```
$(".enter-coupon-input").on("click", function () {
   $(this).select();
}).trigger( "click" );
```

This is working on all browsers on desktop, it is also working on tablets including iOS and Android. But it is not working on any Mobile devices. When I try to select the text inside text field the whole text field get selected, not just text inside text field.

Here is the text field:

```
<input type="text" name="couponcode" id="couponcode" 
 class="enter-coupon-input enter_input_coupon" 
 value="<?php echo $text_here;?>" readonly />
```

Can anyone please tell me why this is not working, I've tried a lot by googling and searching code forums but yet not got any solution.

Comment: You might need to loop into the support of select on the devices you are having issue with. Some may not support it or have a different implementation, common issue on mobile devices.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, perhaps there's some default behavior in mobile browsers for this case

```
$(".enter-coupon-input").on("click", function (е) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).select();
}).trigger( "click" );
```

Comment: Still not working, the whole text field selected while long press on text field

Comment: Or jQuery `e.preventDefault();` doesn't cover the mobile browsers so you should try to prevent the default behavior with pure js.
Consider also the opposite possibility that if any additional framework or libraries, actually piece of their code overrides the default behavior like I'm doing in the example above.
I had such issues in my apps.